# How can use I Exchange Commands on all domain computers?

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, exchange-server-2010

How can call Exchange commands to get mailbox information on a standard domain computer without the Exchange Management Shell installed?

- Run PowerShell directly on remote Exchange server over RDP.
- Invoke-command on a local machine to remote Exchange Server.
- Import-Commands of the Exchange server on a local machine.

Answer (score 0):

I write a script to use localy all exchange 2010+ commands without needed instaling the exchange tools.

use like

```
Import-ExchTools 'MyDomain'
get-mailbox $(whoami)
```

include in your script

```
function Get-RmExchSession ($AD='MyDomain') {
    Get-PSSession | Remove-PSSession
    $SrvBlackList = @('vexchmb7','vexchmb6', 'vexchtopt1')
        $PoolExch = $(
                (Get-ADGroupMember -server $AD 'Exchange Servers') | ?{$_.objectClass -eq 'computer'} | ?{$_.Name -and $SrvBlackList -notcontains $_.name} | Sort-Object -Descending CreationDate | %{
                    [pscustomobject][ordered]@{
                        name = $_.Name
                        dNSHostName = "$($_.Name).$AD.adds"
                    }
                }
        )

    foreach ($exch in $PoolExch) {
        $ExchSession = $null
        #Write-Host $Exch.dNSHostName -nonewline
        if (Test-connexion $Exch.dNSHostName) {
            # on se connecte au dernier Srv exchange mis en place, le plus ressant
            # ne fonctionne pas sur les AD avec approbation unidirectionnele, il faut le credential ADMIN
            $ExchSession = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri "http://$($Exch.dNSHostName)/PowerShell/" -ea SilentlyContinue

            if ($ExchSession) {
                #Write-Host " Session OK" -fore Green
                return $ExchSession
            } else {
                Write-host " Impossible de se connecter avec le Current Credential, tentative avec '$AD\Administrateur'" -fore Red -NoNewline
            }
        }
    }
    $null
}

function Import-ExchTools ($AD='MyDomain') {
    $exchSess = (Get-RmExchSession $AD)
    if ($exchSess) {
        Import-PSSession $exchSess -wa 0 | Out-Null
        $exchSess
    }
    return $null
}
```